# Install all TeXLive documentation for installed packages

Tags: fedora, latex

I have installed some subset of TeXLive on Fedora 22. None of the documentation packages got installed along the way. They are just called texlive-*package*-doc, which is easy. However, I would like to install the documentation packages for all installed packages or at least install the documentation for the [scheme](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive) that I have installed.

Is there any nice way to do this? Perhaps by installing recommended packages along the way? That is a mechanism I know from Debian (recommended and suggested packages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora just recently added "soft" dependencies like recommends and suggests, and they're not widely used yet. Maybe file a bug request against the texlive package?

In the meantime, this should do it:

```
rpm --qf '%{name}\n' -qa 'texlive-*'|xargs -iPKG sudo dnf -y install PKG-doc
```

That lists all of your texlive packages, and installs any corresponding package with the same name and a `-doc` suffix.

Comment: Thanks! The problem seems to be that `dnf` fails when there are packages that do not exist. Additionally I am not very fond of `xargs`. Therefore I took your `rpm` query and [built a Python 3 script around it](https://gist.github.com/martin-ueding/41827b4e566eda32168a) that will check each package for existence first. It is a bit slow as it calls `dnf info` a lot of times, but it seems to work.

Comment: If you're feeling ambitious, you could do this with the [dnf api](http://dnf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html). :)

Comment: Hmmm; the `-i` to xargs should imply `-L1`, so you'll get a bunch of dnf failures, but they won't matter — they're just no-ops.

Comment: Okay, if they run as single commands, the failures are no problem. I see. Using the Python API sounds good, perhaps if I have too much time.